Procedural gradient creates banding... Why?
This is beyond frustrating. I'm using a simple linear gradient on a cube (black to transparent), and I get this awful banding. How can I get rid of it?


How did you obtain this image ? Looks like a 8bit colors limitation but that shouldn't happen before saving the render into an image file.

it's a gradient. I took a screenshot of the viewport

you should render it and check it out there. Does the problem persist in render?

yes, unfortunately
